# (fixed acidity;"volatile acidity";"citric acid";"re...)<-- how do I separate something like this with commas?

Tags: pandas, numpy

I got this dataset (link below), I'm trying to do an exercise for learning TensorFlow and had problems loading the data. The instruction says:

"Read the data into a DataFrame with Pandas.  pd.read_csv would be very useful here. Note, it has an option to specify the delimiter (and the wine csv files are not comma separated). One other note, you should specify a dtype to read_csv: the quality value in the dataset is given as an integer, but our model (a regression model) is expecting a float value."

So, basically I understood that I need to separate the data with commas, also the values for each feature need to be changed to float values, could you please help?

https://archive.ics.uci.edu/ml/machine-learning-databases/wine-quality/winequality-white.csv

cheers!

Comment: You can load the data to pandas using df = pd.read_csv('https://archive.ics.uci.edu/ml/machine-learning-databases/wine-quality/winequality-white.csv', sep = ';')

Comment: There are millions of examples on how to read CSV files with Python. Show us what you tried, what didn't work, et cetera. See https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't need to change it into commas, just use semicolon as a seperator and set the `dtype` to float

```
pd.read_csv('winequality-white.csv', sep=';', dtype='float')
```